# How to make shiny inputs observe and reset each other

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a shiny app.
When I change a single input (cyl), I would like a second input (gear) to reset to a blank value. (and vice versa).
My problem is that when I reset a single input, it seems to reset both inputs.
Put another way, changing (cyl) to 6 resets (gear) to blank, but this also resets (cyl) to blank.
This last behavior is what I am trying to avoid.
Thanks for your help.

Here is a reprex.

```
library(shiny)

df <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  uiOutput("cyl_select")  ,
  uiOutput("gear_select") 
  
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$cyl_select <- renderUI({
    
    selectInput("cyl_select", "cyl_select", unique(c(" ", df$cyl)), selected = c(" "))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gear_select != " ", 
               {
                 
                 updateSelectInput(session, "cyl_select", selected = c(" "))
                 
               })
  
  
  output$gear_select <- renderUI({
    
    
    selectInput("gear_select", "gear_select", unique(c(" ", df$gear)), selected = c(" "))

    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$cyl_select != " ", 
               {
                 
                 updateSelectInput(session, "gear_select", selected = c(" "))
                 
               })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `!= " "` check inside the observer's function. This should work:

```
library(shiny)    
df <- mtcars    
ui <- fluidPage(      
  uiOutput("cyl_select"),
  uiOutput("gear_select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {      
  output$cyl_select <- renderUI({        
    selectInput("cyl_select", "cyl_select", unique(c(" ", df$cyl)), selected = c(" "))        
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gear_select, {
                if (input$gear_select  != " ")  {
                  updateSelectInput(session, "cyl_select", selected = c(" "))
                }                     
               })
  
  
  output$gear_select <- renderUI({        
    selectInput("gear_select", "gear_select", unique(c(" ", df$gear)), selected = c(" "))      
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$cyl_select, {
                 if (input$cyl_select != " ") {
                    updateSelectInput(session, "gear_select", selected = c(" "))
                 }                     
               })      
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, appreciate the help